# Умножение матрицы на столбец. Программа для C

Tags: c, алгоритм

Нужно составить собственные функции для статических и динамических массивов.
Пользователь должен ввести массив и столбец. Программа их перемножает и выдает 2 ответа: один для статического массива, другой для динамического, и они должны быть равными.

Собственную функцию я вроде написал, а дальше не знаю как.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h> 
#define n 4
#define m 3 
int fmass(double *mas,double *masw, int n1, int m1, double *masr)
{
    int k,l,x;
    for(k=0,x=0;k<n1,x<n1;k++,x++)
      for(l=0,masr[k][l]=0.;l<m1;l++)
        masr[k][l]+=mas[k*m1][l]*masw[x];
    return 0;
 }

 int fmasd(double **mas, double *masw, int n1, int m1, double **masr)
 {
     int k,l,x;
     for(k=0,x=0;k<n1,x<n1;k++,x++)
       for(l=0,masr[k][l]=0.;l<m1;l++)
         masr[k]+=mas[k][l]*masw[x];
     return 0;
  }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

> Собственную функцию я вроде написал, а дальше не знаю как.

Написать main, написать создание массивов и заполнение их данными, возможно - ввод данных с клавиатуры и вывод окончательного результата на экран.